# Calculate the overlap area of arbitrary shapes

Tags: java, geometry

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to calculate the overlap area of two arbitrary polygons in Java.

Here's the research I've done so far:

- I've read the documentation of Area class (from java.awt.geom). It doesn't seem to support this option.
- I've tried looking at other classes that may support this, and were offered in other similar occasions (classes that implement Shape interface for example). None of them seemed to have this option.
- I am aware that there are 3rd party modules that support this, but I'm looking for one with free license for every use (including commercial use).

Some more details about the Polygons:

- The only assumption about the polygons is that they are "simple" - i.e - not containing any holes.
- Polygons are given as a list of coordinates. I also have the Area and GeneralPath objects that represents them.

Is there any way to achieve this task in Java without downloading external libraries? 
The only solution I thought of this far is to create for both a set of inner points by finding the bounding rectangle, and using Area's contain function, and then finding the union of both of these sets. The problem with this solution is that it's very inefficient.

Comment: Just write it yourself?

Comment: "I've read the documentation of Area class (from java.awt.geom). It doesn't seem to support this option.": yeah?? look again!! ohh you are looking for very inefficient ohhhhhhhhhhhhhh you want it all then do it your self

Answer (score 0):

You need polygon clipping algorithm suitable for non-convex polygons. Some known algorithms:

- [Vatti's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatti_clipping_algorithm), works with arbitrary polygons, including complex, used in Clipper library
- [Weiler-Atherton algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler%E2%80%93Atherton_clipping_algorithm)
- [Greiner-Hormann algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greiner%E2%80%93Hormann_clipping_algorithm) , page has links to some implementations